# How can I install Ubuntu in 128 MB space?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

My specifications are 128 MB hard disk drive, 512 MB RAM, and 500 MHz CPU.

I only need to run freerdp or rdesktop, absolutely nothing else.

What's the point of the Ubuntu minimal [ISO image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image)? It seems small, but it downloads everything and requires much space anyway.

[Tiny Core Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Core_Linux) fits my hard disk drive, but freerdp and rdesktop doesn't work as expected on it.

Is there any Ubuntu distribution like Tiny Core?

Comment: Doesn't microsoft make software to do this?

Comment: Ubuntu (and its kernel) are *way* too much bloated for 128MB. Have a look into [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/).

Comment: You might have better luck with a BSD variant.

Comment: Which HDD has only 128MB? Does mainboards at that time support RAM as big as 512MB? I remember in the Pentium 2/3 era 128MB of RAM was already a very big number and windows 98 can't support more than 384MB RAM

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744113 https://www.linux.com/news/hardware/desktops/8248-linux-distros-for-older-hardware http://doc.slitaz.org/en:guides:lowramcd

Comment: I would **NEVER** try Ubuntu on such hardware. You could try Puppy Linux, Damn Small Linux, Debian or Arch Linux. If you need GUI, pick either LXDE or a lighter one.

Answer (score 13):

I wouldn't. I don't think it's practical to even *try* to install Ubuntu within 128MB.

Ubuntu is compiled to be useful, not frugal with disk space. A prime example of this is: ***each* of Ubuntu's kernel packages is about 150MB.** It's designed to be flexible, not small.

Yes, you could [roll your own](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile#Alternate_Build_Method_.28B.29:_The_Old-Fashioned_Debian_Way) for just your hardware (`make localmodconfig`) but you'll likely end up needing to roll a lot more too. A customised start-up process, strip out Upstart/Systemd, streamline the Xorg drivers.

Your biggest problem, perhaps, is installing. Assuming you can get the final payload beneath 128MB, the only way I can think to get it on the end device is to do a raw copy onto its media (essentially, flashing it from a virtual install you've done and trimmed elsewhere).

And it's not just the up-front time needed, you also have to consider maintenance. The more you customise, the less can be updated automatically. Keeping on top of security issues will be harder because you won't have somebody compiling and packaging things for you.

So yes, you could spend a lot of time doing this just to get Ubuntu and the useful things Ubuntu brings with it. Or you could use something that is designed to be used on an ancient computer. I know which I'd pick.

Answer (score 10):

> What's the point of ubuntu minimal iso?

To install a *normal* Ubuntu from a very small installation media. Not to install a core system that is basically *not* Ubuntu. Or as is explained on our wiki:

> The minimal iso image will download packages from online archives at installation time instead of providing them on the install media itself. Downloading packages at install time reduces the size of the iso image to approximately ~40MB depending on architecture (see below), as well as providing only the packages needed for installation. The download time savings achieved by using a mini iso can be significant, as only current packages are downloaded, so there is no need to upgrade packages immediately after installation. The mini iso uses a text-based installer, making the image as compact as possible.

> It seems small but downloads everything and requires much space anyway.

True. Since that is not the intention of that install method ;)

> Is there any ubuntu dist like tinycore?

No. See [Are there any linux distros that fit onto a1 128mb usb drive and have a rdp client](https://superuser.com/questions/85033/are-there-any-linux-distros-that-fit-onto-a-128mb-usb-drive-and-have-a-rdp-clien) for alternatives. Ubuntu will not be one of them. [Damn small linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) would be (imo) your best bet (it has rdesktop). Or [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.com/index.html) (also has an RDP)